# Update requests with retry_on_conflict set are not working

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rest-client

I am using the rest client to update some documents and got some version conflict issues. I then added a call to `retryOnConflict(3)` when creating the `UpdateRequest`. However, I still got some conflicts like below:

```
exception [type=version_conflict_engine_exception, reason=[myDocId]: version conflict, document already exists (current version [1])]]
```

The puzzling thing to me here is the currrent version is 1. Since i set retries to 3, it seems like the current version reported in the exception should be have been much higher before Elasticsearch gives up and returns a failure. I debugged my code and confirmed the json content the rest client builds contains the retry parameter. Scripted updates in bulk requests are being done, but otherwise nothing special.

Is this just an issue of a misleading error message or maybe something else is going on?

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to update the same set of documents from two different processes or threads?

Comment: yes, but i think the point of retryOnConflict is to just retry the update if there is a concurrency issue?